# cc1plus: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, g++, compiler-optimization

The cc1plus crashed with the error: `internal compiler error: Segmentation fault`.
I'm wondering why it happened when the computer has enough RAM. I don't think it is the g++'s bug for the compilation can pass after rebooting the computer.
The following are my host's information.

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          62137        3275       55193        1608        3668       56460
Swap:           975         401         574

$ dmesg
[55342.444777] cc1plus[22036]: segfault at 3f5a5cfa6e70 ip 0000000000df4cff sp 00007ffe92d48d60 error 4 in cc1plus[400000+180d000]
[55342.444789] Code: 18 85 f6 0f 88 c1 48 7b ff 83 fe 01 48 89 fb 0f 85 03 48 7b ff 48 85 ff 74 16 8b 57 04 85 d2 74 0f 48 8b 47 18 48 85 c0 74 06 <66> 83 38 03 74 0b 48 83 c4 18 48 89 d8 5b 5d c3 90 83 ea 01 48 63
[57864.997815] ThreadPoolForeg[33416]: segfault at 5549025e409e ip 000055fbf82d388c sp 00007fdd27be01b0 error 4 in code[55fbf6543000+70a6000]
[57864.997826] Code: 01 48 8b 5d b0 4c 89 ad a8 fe ff ff 4c 89 e8 0f b7 48 02 ff c9 66 89 48 02 0f b7 c9 48 c1 e1 04 48 8b 74 08 10 48 8b 44 08 18 <0f> b7 4e fe 66 83 f9 01 77 14 48 8d 4e f8 48 81 e1 00 00 fe ff 48
[57886.041612] traps: make[34363] general protection fault ip:55b6bc81e9b3 sp:7ffffd12f7f0 error:0 in make[55b6bc800000+34000]

$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"
```

- Does the g++ have an configuration to limit its memory usage?
- How to debug the g++'s segment fault issue?

Comment: An internal compiler error is a manifestation of a compiler bug, by definition.

Comment: There are several segfaults, protection faults in your `dmesg` output. This may indicate that something is wrong with your RAM. Try to check it with memtest.

Comment: "compilation can pass after rebooting the computer" Some bugs reproduce every time, others do not. It doesn't matter, a bug is a bug. There is no wiggle room. A program that crashes has a bug. Unless it's a hardware bug.

Comment: Run memtest86+ from a bootable USB.  (Prepare the USB stick on a separate computer; this one probably has RAM that's going bad, so you want to avoid writing `/boot` in your Ubuntu install in case you corrupt that filesystem data.  I think Ubuntu packages memtest86+ / mt86plus, and maybe still includes it on their install media, so you could also risk installing it via apt-get, if you have backups.)